# Within just the visible parts of a dynamic form, how to make certain fields required using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hidden, require

I'm new to programming, so please go easy on me!  I have a dynamic form here, where the fields you fill in change based on a dropdown menu at the beginning.  Certain follow up questions are required and must be filled in, but others are not (and must remain unrequired).  I went through the code below to show you which fields I want required and which I don't.  It would work great as is, except when you factor in the dynamic part (block/none), the required fields from hidden parts of the form prevent it from being submitted.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    function showForm() {
        var selopt = document.getElementById('opts').value;
        if (selopt == 1) {
            document.getElementById('f1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('f2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f3').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f4').style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (selopt == 2) {
            document.getElementById('f1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f2').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('f3').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f4').style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (selopt == 3) {
            document.getElementById('f1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f3').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('f4').style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (selopt == 4) {
            document.getElementById('f1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f3').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f4').style.display = 'block';
        } 
  
        if (selopt == '') {
            document.getElementById('f1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f3').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('f4').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>


<?php
if(!isset($_POST['tripid1'])){
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="entryform">
<select id='opts' onchange='showForm()' required='required'>
    <option value=''>Select Option</option>
    <option value='1'>Species Verification Program / ID</option>
    <option value='2'>Incidental Take Samples</option>
    <option value='3'>Age Structures</option>
    <option value='4'>Special Projects</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<div id='f1' style='display:none'>
Which haul is this sample from? <input type='text' name='tripid1' size='6' required='required'>
Which species is this sample? <input type='text' name='tripid2' size='6' required='required'>
Additional comments optional: <input type='text' name='tripid3' size='6'>
</div>

<div id='f2' style='display:none'>
What species is this? <input type='text' name='tripid1' size='6' required='required'>
What is the tag number? <input type='text' name='tripid2' size='6' required='required'>
Additional comments optional: <input type='text' name='tripid3' size='6'>
</div>

<div id='f3' style='display:none'>
What species? <input type='text' name='tripid1' size='6' required='required'>
Age sample type? <input type='text' name='tripid2' size='6' required='required'>
Additional comments are required: <input type='text' name='tripid3' size='6' required='required'>
</div>

<div id='f4' style='display:none'>
What species is this? <input type='text' name='tripid1' size='6' required='required'>
What is the program? <input type='text' name='tripid2' size='6' required='required'>
Additional comments optional: <input type='text' name='tripid3' size='6'>
</div>
<input type = "submit" value= "SUBMIT FORM" />
</form>
<?php
}

if(isset($_POST['tripid1'])){
echo "Yay, the form submitted!";
}

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to have only one set of inputs, and replace the text as needed. I think this is a nice, easy solution for a self proclaimed beginner:

** Edit ** 
Based on your comments, here is my updated code. First, the HTML. Notice I took out the script tag, as well as the input tags, because we're going to load those dynamically. (Incidentally, you could also load the option tags dynamically as well).

```
<form method="post" id="entryform">
<select id='opts' onchange='showForm()' required='required'>
    <option value=''>Select Option</option>
    <option value='1'>Species Verification Program / ID</option>
    <option value='2'>Incidental Take Samples</option>
    <option value='3'>Age Structures</option>
    <option value='4'>Special Projects</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<div id='f1' style='display:none'>

</div>
<input type = "submit" value= "SUBMIT FORM" />
</form>
```

Now the JavaScript:

```
var questions = {
    "1": "<div id='q1'>Which haul is this sample from? <input type='text' name='tripid1' size='6' required='required'>Which species is this sample? <input type='text' name='tripid2' size='6' required='required'>Additional comments optional: <input type='text' name='tripid3' size='6'></div>",
    "2": "<div id='q2'>What species is this? <input type='text' name='tripid1' size='6' required='required'>What is the tag number? <input type='text' name='tripid2' size='6' required='required'>",
    "3": "<div id='q3'>What species? <input type='text' name='tripid1' size='6' required='required'>Age sample type? <input type='text' name='tripid2' size='6' required='required'>Additional comments are required: <input type='text' name='tripid3' size='6' required='required'></div>",
    "4": "<div id='f4'>What species is this? <input type='text' name='tripid1' size='6' required='required'>What is the program? <input type='text' name='tripid2' size='6' required='required'>Additional comments optional: <input type='text' name='tripid3' size='6'>Here's another question <input type='text' /></div>"    
}    

function showQuestions() {
    // First get what question they chose
    var questionNumber = document.getElementById('opts').value;
    console.log(questionNumber);
    // Now use that to get the questions from the questions object
    var specificQuestions = questions[questionNumber];
    console.log(specificQuestions);
    // Now get the shell div the div
    var shell = document.getElementById('f1');
    // Now inject the HTML
    shell.innerHTML = specificQuestions;
}    

document.getElementById('opts').onchange = showQuestions;
```

We simply load whatever HTML is required. You'll notice question 2 only has 2 questions, question 3 has a required comment, and question 4 has 4 question. Hopefully this fulfills your requirement. You could do more things like add a reset button, do some more error handling, but this should give you an idea of the solution. 
Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29rpe7gr/1/

** End of edit **

You'll notice this also takes care of the the 'required' attribute, which is set to true or false as needed. You'll also notice I took out the php tags. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/29rpe7gr/.

Please allow me to give you a few other ideas. You don't want a form with so many input tags that you're not going to use, because even if you set them as not required, they will all still post to your server as empty texts. That's probably not what you want to do. You only want to send the pertinent answers. This solution provides a template, of sorts, and limits the number of text inputs to the only 3 you care about.

One step further would be to keep the questions in another file as a JavaScript object, and your string replace method will grab the correct question to fill in. The benefit to separating the text and code is that you can easily recycle your code to whatever questions you wish. It also means you don't have to run through any if statements. You can just grab the number from the dropdown menu and use that to get the right questions from your object. This separation of code and content is very standard in programming. Incidentally, I would separate your JavaScript from you HTML by loading an external JS file.

Finally, another step further would be to use a templating engine such as mustache: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js. Although mustache gives you more muscle than you need for this example, it's a great tool to practice coding with.

I hope this helps, let me know if you would like anything cleared up. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, Paul!  That's a very clever solution.  I have an additional question though, I wrote this code snippet as a simplified version of what I'm actually working on, and in actuality not everything has 3 questions.  What if select option 1 has 4 follow up questions, select option 2 has 5, select option 4 has 3, and so on?

Comment: Also, I noticed that it's lost the ability to change the select option to a different category in case the user clicks the wrong thing.  For example, once you select option 1, you get all of the questions for that option, but then if you realize you should have actually selected option 2, and you try to change it, the questions don't update/change.  Thanks again!

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It should address both your comments. Updated fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/29rpe7gr/1/.